# Rotate left operation on IA-32

Tags: assembly, x86

How can a rotate left operation, R1 ← R2 rotate left by 7 bits, can be implemented using the IA-32 instruction set? The contents of R2 should move into R1 after being rotated by 7 bits without R2 being modified.

Comment: What have you tried?  This looks too elementary for this site, and if you'd done some learning on the x86 instruction set and read the manual you should find a solution straightforward.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research to try to solve your problem on your own before asking here, and to show us in the question what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
  MOV R1, R2
  ROL R1, 7
```

(Replace R1 and R2 with real registers like EAX, EBX, ECX etc.)